# How does a Life Oracle's enhanced cures revelation affect wand crafting?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, healing

I am playing a Life Oracle, and I have the enhanced cure revelation which allows my level to be applied to my cure spells instead of using the max given by the spell, so like cure light usually maxes at 1d8+5, but for me at level 8 it maxes at 1d8+8.  So my question is:  When I craft a cure light wand at maximum bonus can I use the +8 or am I stuck to the +5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### It doesn’t affect the wand in any way

There’s just nothing in the Enhanced Cures text that mentions item crafting. The effect does not change the spells themselves, or replace them with different spells.

#### It **does** affect the activation of any *wand of cure X wounds*

> Wands use the spell trigger activation method, so **casting a spell from a wand** is usually a standard action that doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity.

> Enhanced Cures (Su): Whenever you **cast** a *cure* spell

When you activate a wand, you cast the spell it stores. If you activate a *wand of cure X wounds*, it triggers the benefit of Enhanced Cures.

So, in short, when you activate a *wand of cure X wounds*, whether you made it or not, the casting benefits from Enhanced Cures. When someone who doesn’t have the Life Mystery activates a wand, whether you made it or not, they do not benefit.

#### But it is a bad idea to craft a *wand of cure X wounds* with such a high caster level

Caster Level is **very** expensive in a wand (it multiplies the cost, so a *wand of cure light wounds* at Caster Level 11th costs **eleven times** what a *wand of cure light wounds* at Caster Level 1st costs), and *cure X wounds* scale **very slowly** with Caster Level. That wand that costs 11× only heals 1d8+11 instead of 1d8+1: on average, an increase from 5.5 to 15.5. Eleven times the cost, less than three times the effect. That is not a good trade.

When healing with wands, you don’t care about the amount of healing-per-charge or healing-per-use. Healing with wands is fairly slow; it is going to take a minute or so to heal everyone up. The most cost-effective solution is to just get the cheapest wand you can, and burn through more charges. That Caster Level 11th wand might last three times as long, but buying three Caster Level 1st wands is **much cheaper**. Note that you **can** choose to craft magic items at a Caster Level lower than your actual Caster Level, as long as it is still high enough to cast the spell.

If you have Craft Wand yourself, 1st-spell-level, Caster Level 1st wands have the additional advantage of being a thing you can craft in a single night, as it has a base cost of 750 gp.

Comment: Note that you can't apply metamagic to wands, because there's a special clause in the metamagic feats section saying you can't, but it's not generalized to other abilities like this one.

Comment: Just to be clear, mxyzplk means *When you **use** the wand* not *When you **create** the wand*: "With the right item creation feat, you can store a metamagic version of a spell in a scroll, potion, or wand."